# Android scale image to fit

Tags: android

I have an activity with image and two buttons. I'm trying to scale the image, so that two buttons are always visible on screen. Currently image isn't downscaled on small phones, which then causes to button 2 to dissapear. How can I achieve that the image will scale so that other content is always visible on page?

Some images for illustration:

Currently on small phones (second button is dissapears as it is off the screen at the bottom):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk2Ru.jpg

How it should be (Image is downscaled, so both buttons fit):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx5sb.jpg

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may use different image resources for different screen densities, located in the corresponding drawable folders. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

Either use a ScrollView or use layout_weights or set your image height to a certain height like 300dp.